# (nodate) in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

When I print my bibliography I literally see (nodate) in my source when there's no date for an online bibtex entry.
For example:
Apple. (nodate). Introducing Swift. Verkregen 22 december 2014, van https://developer. apple.com/swift/

I wanna get rid of the (nodate), because the APA rules (dutch) say there should be (g.d.) instead of (nodate).

I'm using biblatex with the APA style.
When I use the english-apa as LanguageMapping, I correctly see (n.d.) in the bibliography.
The problem is only happening when I use dutch-apa.
When I use a \parencite{} command, the correct date (g.d.) shows up, the problem only occurs at the \printbibliography.

How can I override the string they use when there's no date? 
I already tried playing around with this line of code, but it doesn't change anything:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{%
nodate = {g.d.}
}

MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa} 

\addbibresource{sources.bib} 
\begin{document} 

\parencite{introducingswift} 
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

with the following code in the sources.bib file:

```
@online{introducingswift,
    title = {Introducing {S}wift},
    author = {Apple},
    url = {https://developer.apple.com/swift/},
    urldate = {2014-12-22},
}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even though the idea of your question is quite clear (at least I think I got it), your question would benefit from a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Just so we have something to play around with and so we can actually see the problem. When I just wrote my own short example document based on what was my best guess for your document, I got "g.d." in the citations as well as the bibliography.

Comment: Is the "nodate" in bold (that would indicate the `nodate` string does not exist for some reason, in that case there would also be a warning in the `.log`)? Is it in two words or with a space in between? What version of `biblatex` are you using?

Comment: I added an MWE to my original question. 
"nodate" isn't in bold. It's in one word, so without a space.
It's only happening in the \printbibliography, not in the \parencite{}.

Comment: Even with in your MWE I get "g.d." everywhere. Before you do anything else, please make sure `biblatex` as well as `biblatex-apa` are up-to-date on your machine. You could try `\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \literal{nodate}
}` or `\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
}` (modulo line breaks) not sure if this will help though.

Comment: The fact that it is "nodate" in one word without space suggests it is hard-coded and not a localisation. As it is not bold it is not standard `biblatex` fallback for missing strings. So what remains is a hardcoded string in `biblatex-apa`. In my version of `biblatex-apa` (v6.7), "nodate" appears only in the lines I suggested above.

Comment: How can I update my biblatex or biblatex-apa? I use an IDE (texpad) so I didn't get in contact with these at all. I only installed mactex.

Comment: Maybe [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864) helps? Make sure to read the "Understanding the TeX Live update scheme" section in the TeXLive part of the answers, it is also relevant to MacTeX.

Comment: Thanks alot. My distribution is updating at the moment. I hope that solves the problem! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Alright, updating my distribution fixed the problem :) Thanks alot for helping me out! Too bad I can't mark your comment as answer yet. Maybe you can add an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was fixed by updating the OP's TeX distribution.